# What is the pronunciation of the prefixes "ver-" and "ge-"?

Tags: pronunciation

Should "ver-" be pronounced as [fɐ] or [fɛɐ]?

Should "ge-", be pronounced as [gə] or [gɛ]?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is, it depends. Can you provide some more context?

Comment: Dialect and individual disposition reign this. The more northwest you get, the more affinity people have to *ə*, when southeasterners would settle on *ɐ*. All the variants you listed are okay, you may even hear no vowel at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### ver-

The standard pronunciation of the prefix *ver-* is **[fɛɐ̯].** But in many regions people use colloquial speech and pronounce it as **[fɐ].** In some regions you also will hear **[fɔɐ̯].**

---

### ge-

The standard pronunciation of the prefix *ge-* is **[ɡə].** But here again there are regions where you will hear **[gɛ]** and others where people say **[ɡe].**